# Finding the exact string in input file

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am looking for the lines starting with "ND" in an input file.
that looks like this:

```
ND 195 4.53434033e+006 5.62453069e+006 2.56369141e+002
ND 196 4.53436645e+006 5.62443565e+006 2.56452118e+002
NS  129 113 97 82 58 59 37 22 17 18
NS  5 6 12 26 42 64 62 85 102 117
```

I wrote a code like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

found_ND = False
text = "ND"
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f, open('output.dat', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in f:
        if text in line:
           found_ND = True
        if found_ND:
            #do whatever you want
            try:
                line = line.strip()
                columns = line.split()
                i = float(columns[1])
                x = float(columns[2])
                y = float(columns[3])
                z = float(columns[4])
                print(z)
                print("{:.2f}".format(z), file=outfile)
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

But in the result I get also the fourth column of the string starting with "NS".
Result looks like this:

```
256.37
256.45
82.00
26.00
```

How can I write the code to avoid the lines starting with `"NS"`?

Comment: You mean `if line.startswith('ND ') try....`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're using a flag `found_ND`, making it `True` if the line is found (which happens for the first line) and then never change it back to `False`:

```
if text in line:
    found_ND = True
```

*`found_ND` will be `True` for all following iterations*. In short, just don't use a flag, you don't need it:

```
for line in f:
    if text in line:
        #do whatever you want
        try:
            line = line.strip()
            columns = line.split()
            # .. and so on.
```

or, if you strictly want to check the beginning (that is, the line might contain `'ND'` elsewhere) use `startswith` as @Wiktor suggested:

```
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('ND '):
        # ...
```